# Changing input dimension of Model zoo's Mobilenet-SSD V2

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have used the pretrained ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8 for real time object detection. The default input dimension is 320 x 320 for the model. I want to experiment on changing it to 100x100 or 200x200 but when I change the config file it results to an error. How can I fix this?

This is the Edit to the config file apart from the paths.

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 36
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 100
        width: 100
      }
    }
```

The Error

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8 and 7 for '{{node ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/top_down/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/top_down/nearest_neighbor_upsampling/nearest_neighbor_upsampling/Reshape_1, ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/top_down/projection_2/BiasAdd)' with input shapes: [4,8,8,128], [4,7,7,128].


        Call arguments received:
          • image_features=[("'layer_7'", 'tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 13, 13, 32), dtype=float32)'), ("'layer_14'", 'tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 7, 7, 96), dtype=float32)'), ("'layer_19'", 'tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 4, 4, 1280), dtype=float32)')]


    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 100, 100, 3), dtype=float32)
      • kwargs={'training': 'False'}
```

Comment: How do you change the config file? and what is the error? Please share your code and the error message. Thanks

Comment: I've edited the problem

Comment: Your input dimension is not compatible with the model architecture. try other dimensions, such as 128, 256, 300 and so on.

Comment: Thank you its working now, but how do I know which input dimensions are compatible. Is there a formula too use or should they just be divisible by a certain number?

Comment: Thank you very much after, testing the configs i found out that the compatible input dimensions should be divisible by 32.

Answer (score 0):

At the pipeline config when you using Tensorflow Object Detection API:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1 
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: your desired height
        width: your desired width
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, that your input dimension is not compatible with the model architecture.

So Try other input dimensions, such as 128, 256, and every other dimension that is divisible by 32.